# Check if two graphs have same shape

Tags: graphs-and-networks, topology

How can I check if two graphs have same shape or not? By shape I mean the two graphs are equivalent under a set of "name" replacements, like:

```
Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}] == Graph[{1->3,3->2,2->1}]
Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}] != Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->4,4->1}]
```

And by the way how can I check if they have same topological(?) shape, which means

```
Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}] == Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->4,4->1}]
Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->1}] != Graph[{1->2,2->3,3->4,4->1,1->5,5->2,2->1}]
```

Comment: for same "shape", see [IsomorphicGraphQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IsomorphicGraphQ.html). E.g. `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]~IsomorphicGraphQ~
 Graph[{1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 1}]` gives `True`.

Comment: In Mathematica 11.2 on my mechine, it turns out `IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph[...],Graph[...]]` will not evaluate, while  `IsomorphicGraphQ[{a[1, 1, 3, 1] ->
   a[1, 1, 3, 1]}, {a[1, 1, 1, 3] -> a[1, 1, 1, 3]}]` will return false (incorrectly?). I use this kind of "a-tuple" as vertexes since they are generated by `NestGraph` while it will not work correctly if I return list of list (it will be considered matrix).

Comment: Fix above: It turns out that `IsomorphicGraphQ` of anything beside `Graph[...]` will always return false, even for `IsomorphicGraphQ[{1 -> 2}, {1 -> 2}]`, while  `IsomorphicGraphQ` of `Graph[...]` do not evaluate (it will return the same thing as input). Is that a bug on my mechine or bug of 11.2?

Comment: ZisIsNotZ, The two arguments of  `IsomorphicGraphQ` should be graphs: `IsomorphicGraphQ[Graph@{1 -> 2}, Graph@{1 -> 2}]` gives `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equivalence you mention is called [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). Use [`IsomorphicGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IsomorphicGraphQ.html).

The second is not entirely clear to me, but you probably mean [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)).

It seems reasonable (but I have not proven it!) that two directed graphs would be homeomorphic if we obtain isomorphic graphs after repeatedly removing vertices that have one incoming and one outgoing edge, like vertex `2` below, and replacing them with a single edge (would be `1 -> 3` below).

[image]

To avoid obtaining multigraphs or self loops, the removal should only be done if vertices `1` and `3` are distinct and there is no edge `1 -> 3` already.

Here's an implementation of this for directed graphs (since that is what you have in your example):

```
out[g_, v_] := First@DeleteCases[VertexOutComponent[g, v], v]
in[g_, v_] := First@DeleteCases[VertexInComponent[g, v], v]

smooth[graph_?DirectedGraphQ]:=
    Module[{g=graph,candidates,v},
        While[True,
            candidates=Pick[VertexList[g],Transpose[{VertexOutDegree[g],VertexInDegree[g]}],{1,1}];
            candidates=Select[candidates, With[{i=in[g,#1],o=out[g,#1]},!EdgeQ[g,i\[DirectedEdge]o]&&i=!=o]&];
            If[candidates==={},Break[]];
            v=First[candidates];
            g=VertexContract[g,{v,out[g,v]}]
        ];
        g
    ]

homeomorphicQ[g1_?DirectedGraphQ, g2_?DirectedGraphQ] := 
 IsomorphicGraphQ[smooth[g1], smooth[g2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To check that two *undirected* graphs have the same topological shape, now you can use `IGHomeomorphicQ` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) 0.3.99 or later.

For example,

[image]

The `IGSmoothen` function will smooth out degree-2 vertices like this:

[image]

Check the documentation for more examples.

Here's a copyable snippet:

```
IGHomeomorphicQ[CycleGraph[3], CycleGraph[4]]
(* True *)
```